# Error TS4053: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name ‘Observable’

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i'm trying to build app with ionic 2 & angular 2,
i get this error while i try to run my app.
i build another project to check and the same problem, 
i really confused on this problem.

[image: error in photo]

this is my service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";


/*
  Generated class for the MyService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public local :Storage;
  public getsession : any;
  constructor(private http: Http, private navCtrl : NavController) {
    this.local = new Storage();
    console.log("my-service page")
  }

  postLogin(data){
    let link = "http://adirzoari.16mb.com/login.php";
    return this.http.post(link,data)
        .map(res => res.json())
  }

  checkToken(){
    return this.getsession =this.local.get('token');
  }

}
```

Comment: Import Observable
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
and make 
postLogin(data): Observable<any> {

Comment: I had the same kind of error when using a recursive type

Answer (score 66, accepted):

*I only add this as an answer so it could help other SO users facing the same issue.*

Just like [@sudheer-kb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4915541/sudheer-kb) mentioned, in order to solve that issue, you need to **explicitly** import the `Observable` class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
// ...
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"; // <- add this import
```

And then give your method an explicit return type (also thanks [@ruffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028230/ruffin) for your comment):

```
postLogin(data): Observable<any> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: for rxjs 6 `import { Observable } from "rxjs";`

Comment: This really helped. However I just imported { Observable } but never used in a code as I was playing with BehaviorSubject and Subject. But without Observable import it was giving error.

Comment: @KushalJayswal My guess is that you *were* using the type -- *as a return value from a function*, but [without giving an explicit return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870881/error-ts4053-return-type-of-public-method-from-exported-class-has-or-is-using-n#comment94922860_40525022). As sudheer says, you should **also** make `postLogin(data) {` read `postLogin(data): Observable<any> {`. tslint yells at me if I only import. Doing both makes tslint (and future coders) happiest.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue, it seems related to a problem with return types of methods. What worked for me is to simply add ": any" just after declaration of my methods, like this for example :

```
get(url) : any {
  //code
}
```

I don't think it's a good habit, but it can be a good fix sometimes.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer until a fix is pushed into the Angular2 platform.  It's simple, and it works when this error pops up. Usually, the error is related to a specific method unless you have a lot of "like" methods, then the other solution above seems more appropriate.

Comment: It was that for me ! Thank you .

Comment: @rjdamore I may be missing a 2016 ng2 bug, but this solution only works because it drops strong typing. Compiler: "*Wait, you're returning a type that's not referenced.*" This solution: "*Aw, don't worry about the type.*" That is, usually the line is `get(url) {` with no return type specified. **Declaring a strongly typed return type** seems a better solution than the grenade: `get(url): SomeType {`. <<< This solution (and [sudheer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870881/#comment67029598_39870881)): "*Okay compiler, let me tell you the correct type [which requires importing it too].*"

Comment: @ruffin I didn't say it was the best solution but sometimes you don't want to waste too much time on what I would call a compiler problem.